# Riemann-Stieljes Integral, variable substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider a function $f\in R(\alpha)$ in $[a,b]$ and $\phi:[c,d]\rightarrow
[a,b]$ strictly increasing with $\phi(c)=a$ and $\phi(d)=b$, show that 
$$\int fd\alpha = \int (f\circ \phi) d(\alpha\circ\phi)$$.

I'm convinced that this theorem is false for some functions, but the counter-example I found has both $f\circ\phi$ and $\alpha\circ\phi$ discontinuous at the same point and I have no idea how to consider the integrability of double-discontinuous functions. Is the minimal condition on $\phi$ for this to be true bijectivity(and therefore continuity?).
For reference, the counter example I found is based on the idea that there can be an open interval $[a,b]\supset (a_1,b_1) \not\subset\phi([c,d])$.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified much about $f$ and $\alpha$ other than $f \in \mathcal{R}_\alpha([a,b])$. Nevertheless, these hypotheses **along with** $\phi \in C([c,d])$ makes this result true.  This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3183303/148510).

On the other hand, if you can find a counterexample where $f \circ \phi$ and $\alpha \circ \phi$ are both discontinuous from the right or both discontinuous from the left at just one point, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral cannot exist.  If one is discontinuous only from the right and the other is discontinuous only from the left then the integral could exist.

I prove this non-existence of the integral (with the double discontinuity)  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2534873/148510), using the relatively weak condition that  the integrator is of bounded variation.

I have never thought about what might happen in the case where  the integrator has unbounded variation yet the integral exists, but this is rare.